# How to enable when checkbox is checked correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to enable a button when a checkbox is checked but I don't know what I'm doing wrong with my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".checkboxdav").on("change", function(e) {
    if ($(".checkboxdav").attr("checked")) {
      $(".submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $(".submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkboxdav" id="customCheck1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Declaro que tengo la autorización del
        propietario del vehículo para suministrar sus datos a Davivienda para la compra del
        SOAT.</label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="submit primary-btn px-4 py-2"
        disabled>Cotizar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: any console errors? Also what is `.button('enable')` ?

Comment: Fix your HTML as well

Comment: Change the `.button('enable')` but no console error with this new change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkboxdav" id="customCheck1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Declaro que tengo la autorización del
                        propietario del vehículo para suministrar sus datos a Davivienda para la compra del
                        SOAT.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="submit primary-btn px-4 py-2"
                        disabled>Cotizar</button>
                </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".checkboxdav").on("change", function(e) {
    if ($(".checkboxdav").is(":checked")) {
      $(".submit").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $(".submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Works to me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `checked` attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the `checked` property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property like:

- `if ( elem.checked )`
- `if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )`
- `if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )`

So, you can update your code like:

```
if ($(".checkboxdav").is(":checked")) {
   $(".submit").prop('disabled', false);
} else {
   $(".submit").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: I got this on console `jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).button is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.eval (index.js?b635:7)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js?1157:5237)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js?1157:5044)`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
$('.checkboxdav').on('change', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#submit-form').attr('disabled', true);
     } else {
         $('#submit-form').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
});
```